# No module named 'captcha.fields'

Tags: python, captcha

Hi~I have got a ModuleNotFoundError saying "No module named 'captcha.fields'" when I run manage.py in my Django project. 
[image]

I confirm that django-simple-captcha has been installed and successfully imported into my programme. But I check the captcha package and I haven't found any definition for captcha.fields.
Could anyone help me, please? Thank you.

Comment: How did you install `django-simple-captcha`?

Comment: pip3 install django-simple-captcha

Answer (score 4):

```
pip install django-recaptcha
```

**use this to install package in your python environment**

Answer (score 3):

Simply uninstall the package from your virtual environment and reinstall it. Do migrate if need be. The issue should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

If You have problem in `from captcha.fields import CaptchaField` like me.

Just install `django-simple-captcha`

> `pip install django-simple-captcha`

I try install `django-recaptcha` and `captcha` but doesn't work. But  `django-simple-captcha` is worked.